# jquery: collecting all icon images and inserting them after each h2 element for mobile view

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a webpage with 6 or 7 different h2 sections.  What I mean by that, is there is an h2 header and then several elements after until the next h2.  Within these sections are icons in the format of `<div class="icon"><img ...></div>`

On mobile view, I need to collect these icons and insert them directly after the h2 headers.

I've tried the following, and variations using nextUntil(), nextAll(), after, etc.

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('h2').each(function() {
            jQuery(this).after(jQuery(this).nextUntil('h2', '.icon img'));
        });
    });
</script>
```

I can't seem to locate the icon divs after each matched h2 element.  Any help in achieving this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example It may also be good to take the Tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Can you setup a JSFiddle with the HTML too?